# I can only eat oranges without becoming lethargic. Why?

Tags: diet, health-risk

If I eat anything besides fresh oranges, tomatoes pineapples and watermelons I get dumb, slow and loose all track of time. Why? Eating nothing cases completely different problems. Right now I pretty much juice 18 pounds of oranges a day and 2 pounds of chicken every 4 days. This is not due to BMI as I am underweight and have been as far back as I remember. Google says 10 lb of oranges=2,126 calories.